# I am stuck in a java code and i dont understant why it is not return true

Tags: java

This Java code below is not returning true in if else statement...

```
public class DecimalComparator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(25.367876,25.367873));
    }

    public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a, double b){

        DecimalFormat threePreshizen = new DecimalFormat("###.###");
        String aNew = threePreshizen.format(a);
        String bNew = threePreshizen.format(b);

        System.out.println(aNew);
        System.out.println(bNew);

        if (aNew == bNew){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to return "true".

Comment: Compare Strings with .equals(). Also, just `return aNew.equals(bNew)` and remove the if/else

Comment: You are comparing two different object. Use the .equals() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your if block with the following:

```java
return aNew.equals(bNew);
```

This returns a boolean based on if content of the two strings matches, rather than if the value of their memory reference is identical.

If you expect either of your strings to be `null`, instead use

```java
return Objects.equals(aNew, bNew);
```

Comment: Thank you Austin Schäfer. I solved it

Comment: Please accept the answer then so that anyone who runs into this question in the future can reference it.